# Syncing my git repos across Mac and Linux box for continuous build

Tags: linux, macos, gradle, rsync, continuous-build

I am looking for a way to sync my git repositories from my Mac to an Intel NUC box I have running Ubuntu.  The reason I want to do this is to take the load off my Mac for builds, and just have my Ubuntu box do this when it receives a change to one of the repos.  Also, I'd like it to be automatic so that i can play about with Gradles continuous build feature. Has anyone done anything like this, or is this possible?  I've been looking into rsync and thinking this is the way to go, but was looking other inputs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Is the git repository located on your mac and you would like to syncronize it to your linux box whenever a change is made in the repository?

Answer (score 0):

That's the basic functionality of version control, you can have the same copy of repo on any number of machines.

You can clone your repository on any other machine (linux, window or another mac). Then run a cron job to pull latest changes on new machine periodically.

Comment: Yeah, i was hoping not to have to do push and pulls, but rather have it automated so that i can use Gradles continuous build feature on the Linux box.

Comment: ok, then I think you are going in right direction with 'rsync' approach

Answer (score 0):

I really love this tool - [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/)

1. Download binaries for your systems
2. Run on both machines (just execute one file)
3. Connect machines to each other
4. Add desired folders to be synchronized

Answer (score 0):

I am trying something similar, unison is a nice alternative.

- https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison

The latest version comes with a `repeat` configuration option that allows you to run it as a service. Doesn't have all the bells and whistles of a gui, but is basically similar to bidirectional rsync with conflict management.